# How to add a javascript array variable into mongodb using node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have defined a schema for add question and its like

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
question_set : String,
questions:[{
    question_id : String,
    question_no : Number
}]
});
```

I would like to insert variables say, `ques_set = 'xyz'` and an array 
`question_array = [['id_1',1],['id_2',2],['id_3',3]]`.

I used this code to insert to mongodb

```
var questions = require('../schemas/questions');

exports.testing = function(req,res){
  if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400)

  var ques_set = 'xyz';
  var  question_array = [['id_1',1],['id_2',2],['id_3',3]];
  var data = question({ques_set,question_array);


      data.save(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      else {
        console.log('Question Inserted');
        res.send("Question Inserted");    
      }
      });


  };
```

This shows me an error `TypeError: object is not a function`. Please help me, I just started nodejs. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a question object that matches your schema, something like this:

```
var Question = require('../schemas/questions');
exports.testing = function(req,res){
    if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400)

    var ques_set = 'xyz';
    var question_array = [
        {
            question_id: "id_1",
            question_no: 1
        },
        {
            question_id: "id_2",
            question_no: 2
        },
        {
            question_id: "id_3",
            question_no: 3
        }
    ];

    var data = Question({question_set: ques_set, questions: question_array});

    data.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else {
            console.log('Question Inserted');
            res.send("Question Inserted");    
        }
    });
  };
```

Comment: Thank you @chridam, for help. I thought it will take javascript arrays, my ignorance! BTW `var data = Question({question_set: ques_set, questions: question_array);` this statement needs a closing braces.

Comment: @user85544 Thank you for spotting the mistake and I'm glad you found this useful :-)